# Is it possible to apply Z-index using HTML?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a long vertical email form that I am editing from an old template made out of tables and the widths don't match up perfectly all the way down so what I intend to do is add a div or image etc behind all the tables so it is just wider than the widest table and it will hide the messy table layout and make the email form look unified and neat.

I've done a similar thing in the past but using z-index on CSS. As I am sending this to Outlook I don't want to use CSS.

Sorry if my post is confusing. Any help appreciated

Comment: you can apply z-index using style tag, like: style="z-index:1000000"

Comment: `z-index` is a CSS concept, so it is logically impossible to use it without CSS. You can, however, as described in answers, use it without using an external stylesheet and even without a `style` element, namely using a `style` attribute. But its content is still CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**, it is not possible to do that with HTML only unless and until you are willing to change the order of your markup, else as far as the CSS goes, you can use `z-index` inline for that particular element.

So for example

```
<div style="z-index: /* Whatever */"></div>
```

Comment: its worth to note that z-index will only work on positioned elements such as absolute or relative.

Comment: @sulfureous yea, thanks for commenting, upvoted so that people will refer :)

Comment: While your answer is true, it is important to note that z-index is not allowed as a styling property in most major modern mail clients. It has too many security issues, like hiding harmful content and hidden links.

Comment: @RLacorne Well, that depends on OP whether to use that or not, doesn't mean we have to down vote answers :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah sorry for the downvote, but since the OP clearly stated that it was gonna be sent to outlook accounts, your answer is not the right one, as outlook will not display z-index. If you want to be more precise in your answer, I'll gladly upvote it. :)

Comment: @RLacorne Nah, glad you answered, OP will select the right one whatever is helpful to him :)

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that inline styling works across all major modern mail clients, z-index does not. I'm sorry to have to say this, but you're probably gonna have to rebuild your nested tables from the ground up if their sizes don't match.

As a quick example: Outlook 2007 uses word as a rendering engine. z-index will never display with that client, therefore will completely break your layout. And a lot of people still use outlook 2007, like it or not.

If you need some layering effects, you'll have to use plain old images and cut those so they fit in table cells. It's a pain, but that's part of the html-email world, and that's probably what you are being paid for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline` CSS. This works in outlook and all other email clients.